# How to provide the password at powershell file when requested

Tags: powershell

I am using a powershel file in which I have included several lines with commands. When I run the command which needs to connect the PC to my Raspberry pi, it asks for password.

pi@192.168.100.7's password:

the password is PAOK and I would like to aks how do I have to write it in the powershell file in order to be submitted automatically.

I have tried just to write in the powershell file but in vain.

pscp -r * pi@192.168.100.7:/home/pi/AgriIOT/DHT
PAOK

Comment: It seems there's a `-pw` param for passwords (https://superuser.com/questions/532919/how-to-use-pscp-to-copy-file-from-unix-machine-to-windows-machine-where-target-p)

Comment: PSCP is putty, just look for putty commands `-l username -pw password`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use the -pw parameter:
pscp -r -pw PAOK * pi@192.168.100.7:/home/pi/AgriIOT/DHT

Thank you Dhruv Murarka and ArcSet